# Continuity of Inner product

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ and $g$ be continuous mapping of $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ into $\mathbb{R}^m$. Show that the inner product
$h(x) = \langle f(x),g(x)\rangle$ is continuous.

Comment: Products of continuous maps are continuous, and composition of continuous maps are continuous.

Answer (score 7):

The inner product is defined from $h: C(S)\times C(S) \to \mathbb{R}$, where $C(S)$ is continuous function from $S\to \mathbb{R}^m$.

To prove the continuity of $f$, we use the sequential criterion. That is, suppose $f_n \to f, g_n \to g$ in $S$, show $h_n =\langle f_n, g_n\rangle \to h = \langle f, g\rangle$.

Indeed it is true by the Cauchy Schwarz inequality, that is

\begin{align}
\lvert\langle f_n, g_n\rangle - \langle f, g\rangle\rvert &= \lvert\langle f_n, g_n\rangle - \langle f_n, g\rangle + \langle f_n, g\rangle - \langle f,g\rangle\rvert\\
&\leq \lvert\langle f_n, g_n\rangle - \langle f_n, g\rangle\rvert + \lvert\langle f_n, g\rangle - \langle f,g\rangle\rvert\\
&\leq \lVert f_n\rVert \cdot \lVert g_n-g\rVert + \lVert f_n-f\rVert \cdot \lVert g\rVert
\end{align}

and $\lVert f_n\rVert$ is bounded by convergence.

Comment: That is all I would have to do? @JohnZHANG

Comment: @juniormath Yes. I think it is.

Comment: Are you using the claim $\langle f_n, g_n \rangle - \langle f, g \rangle = \langle f_n - f, g_n - g \rangle$ on the last line?

Comment: @epimorphic I have edited my answer.